# Error en rutas de React, usando Breeze-Inertia-Laravel10. " Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: ... "

Tags: laravel, reactjs, breeze

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en Laravel 10, usando react con inertia y breeze.
En desarrollo, con npm run dev, puedo ver mis rutas de react sin problema.
En el hosting de producción, utilizando npm run build, al intentar acceder a una ruta de una page de react, obtengo el siguiente error:
Ejemplo dominio.com/constructor
"Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Constructor.jsx."

[image: Imagen de mi error en pantalla]

Mi archivo app.jsx

````
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: async (name) =>
        resolvePageComponent(
            `./pages/${name}.jsx`,
            import.meta.glob("./pages/**/*.jsx")
        ),setup({ el, App, props }) {
            const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    
            let selectedLayout;
            // Ejemplo de condición para seleccionar el layout basado en la ruta
            if (currentPath.startsWith("/constructor") || currentPath.startsWith("/comentarios")) {
                selectedLayout = <ConstructorLayout>{/* Puedes añadir props específicas aquí */}</ConstructorLayout>;
                createRoot(el).render(
                    React.cloneElement(selectedLayout, null, <App {...props} />)
                );
            }else{
                
                createRoot(el).render(
                    
                        <App {...props} />
                    
                );
            }
    
           
        }, ```


Ejemplo de mi vite.config.js
``` export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.jsx',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [forms],
}; ```
````